# Hibernate - COALESCE with aggregation function not working on empty database

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to prepare a query in HQL, which will return BigDecimal.ZERO if there are no matching rows in database, or sum of particular field, if there is any row.

Query works, when there is something in database, but throws NoResultException, when table is empty.
Can you please tell me, what is wrong with following code?

```
public BigDecimal getNumberOfUnitsFor(String tfiCode) {
    String query =  "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(unit.units), 0.0) " +
                    "FROM TFIUnitPurchase unit " +
                    "INNER JOIN TFI tfi on tfi.uid = unit.tfi " +
                    "WHERE tfi.code = :code " +
                    "GROUP BY tfi.code";
    Session session = getSession();
    BigDecimal sum = session.createQuery(query, BigDecimal.class)
                    .setReadOnly(true)
                    .setParameter("code", tfiCode)
                    .getSingleResult();
    session.close();
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out. It was due to GROUP BY clause. After removing it, everything works fine. Topic can be closed.